# Problem with start WPF app

Tags: wpf

Hi I have problem run wpf app from *.exe file.

In Visual Studio is no problem tu start instance.

In project I use caliburn.micro, MEF etc but I think problem is on another place.

WPF app is build as release version for Any CPU and .NET Framework 4.

OS is Windows 7 Enterprise 64bit.

If I try run exe file I get this error: **NameOfApp has stopped working**

Files that help describe the problem:

- C:\Users\Jan\AppData\Local\Temp\WERE902.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
- C:\Users\Jan\AppData\Local\Temp\WER89.tmp.appcompat.txt
- C:\Users\Jan\AppData\Local\Temp\WER116.tmp.mdmp

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

**C:\Users\Jan\AppData\Local\Temp\WERE902.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml contains:**

```
<WERReportMetadata>
−
<OSVersionInformation>
<WindowsNTVersion>6.1</WindowsNTVersion>
<Build>7600 </Build>
<Product>(0x1b): Windows 7 Enterprise N</Product>
<Edition>EnterpriseN</Edition>
<BuildString>7600.16617.amd64fre.win7_gdr.100618-1621</BuildString>
<Revision>1</Revision>
<Flavor>Multiprocessor Free</Flavor>
<Architecture>X64</Architecture>
<LCID>1033</LCID>
</OSVersionInformation>
−
<ProblemSignatures>
<EventType>CLR20r3</EventType>
<Parameter0>spirit_caliburn_micro_v1.0.exe</Parameter0>
<Parameter1>1.0.0.0</Parameter1>
<Parameter2>4d1e2824</Parameter2>
<Parameter3>PresentationFramework</Parameter3>
<Parameter4>4.0.0.0</Parameter4>
<Parameter5>4ba1f8db</Parameter5>
<Parameter6>78ff</Parameter6>
<Parameter7>0</Parameter7>
<Parameter8>System.Windows.Markup.XamlParse</Parameter8>
</ProblemSignatures>
−
<DynamicSignatures>
<Parameter1>6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.27</Parameter1>
<Parameter2>1033</Parameter2>
<Parameter22>0a9e</Parameter22>
<Parameter23>0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789</Parameter23>
<Parameter24>0a9e</Parameter24>
<Parameter25>0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789</Parameter25>
</DynamicSignatures>
−
<SystemInformation>
<MID>8F2179F4-737D-485D-9CAC-B1D77B8D75DC</MID>
<SystemManufacturer>Micro-Star International</SystemManufacturer>
<SystemProductName>GX700</SystemProductName>
<BIOSVersion>080014</BIOSVersion>
</SystemInformation>
</WERReportMetadata>
```

**C:\Users\Jan\AppData\Local\Temp\WER89.tmp.appcompat.txt contains:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<DATABASE>
<EXE NAME="Spirit_Caliburn_Micro_v1.0.exe" FILTER="CMI_FILTER_PRIVACY">
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="Caliburn.Micro.dll" SIZE="61440" CHECKSUM="0x782C091B" BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Caliburn Micro" COMPANY_NAME="Blue Spire Consulting, Inc." PRODUCT_NAME="Caliburn.Micro" FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="Caliburn.Micro.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="Caliburn.Micro.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright © 2010" VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" LINK_DATE="12/31/2010 18:59:05" UPTO_LINK_DATE="12/31/2010 18:59:05" VER_LANGUAGE="Language Neutral [0x0]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="log4net.dll" SIZE="270336" CHECKSUM="0x83401475" BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.2.10.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.2.0.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="1.2" FILE_DESCRIPTION="log4net for .NET Framework 2.0" COMPANY_NAME="The Apache Software Foundation" PRODUCT_NAME="log4net" FILE_VERSION="1.2.10.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="log4net.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="log4net.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright 2001-2006 The Apache Software Foundation." VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x47251" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.2.10.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.2.0.0" LINK_DATE="03/30/2006 12:24:26" UPTO_LINK_DATE="03/30/2006 12:24:26" VER_LANGUAGE="Language Neutral [0x0]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="Newtonsoft.Json.dll" SIZE="319488" CHECKSUM="0x8097DC7D" BIN_FILE_VERSION="3.5.0.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="3.5.0.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="3.5.0.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Newtonsoft Json.NET" COMPANY_NAME="Newtonsoft" PRODUCT_NAME="Newtonsoft Json.NET" FILE_VERSION="3.5.0.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="Newtonsoft.Json.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="Newtonsoft.Json.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright © Newtonsoft 2008" VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x52B36" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="3.5.0.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="3.5.0.0" LINK_DATE="08/14/2010 01:55:19" UPTO_LINK_DATE="08/14/2010 01:55:19" VER_LANGUAGE="Language Neutral [0x0]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="Observable_Dictionary.dll" SIZE="7680" CHECKSUM="0x251864D9" BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="ObservableDictionary" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft" PRODUCT_NAME="ObservableDictionary" FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="Observable_Dictionary.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="Observable_Dictionary.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright © Microsoft 2010" VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" LINK_DATE="12/31/2010 18:59:04" UPTO_LINK_DATE="12/31/2010 18:59:04" VER_LANGUAGE="Language Neutral [0x0]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="Pokec_Toolkit.dll" SIZE="20480" CHECKSUM="0x6A84165A" BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Pokec_Toolkit" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft" PRODUCT_NAME="Pokec_Toolkit" FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="Pokec_Toolkit.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="Pokec_Toolkit.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright © Microsoft 2010" VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" LINK_DATE="12/31/2010 12:32:19" UPTO_LINK_DATE="12/31/2010 12:32:19" VER_LANGUAGE="Language Neutral [0x0]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="Pokec_Toolkit_InterfaceAssembly.dll" SIZE="29184" CHECKSUM="0x1EB74D41" BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Pokec_Toolkit_InterfaceAssembly" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft" PRODUCT_NAME="Pokec_Toolkit_InterfaceAssembly" FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="Pokec_Toolkit_InterfaceAssembly.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="Pokec_Toolkit_InterfaceAssembly.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright © Microsoft 2010" VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" LINK_DATE="12/31/2010 18:59:25" UPTO_LINK_DATE="12/31/2010 18:59:25" VER_LANGUAGE="Language Neutral [0x0]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="Spirit_Caliburn_Micro_v1.0.exe" SIZE="1052672" CHECKSUM="0x9D8231C1" BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Spirit" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft" PRODUCT_NAME="Spirit" FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="Spirit_Caliburn_Micro_v1.0.exe" INTERNAL_NAME="Spirit_Caliburn_Micro_v1.0.exe" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright © Microsoft 2010" VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x1" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" LINK_DATE="12/31/2010 18:59:48" UPTO_LINK_DATE="12/31/2010 18:59:48" VER_LANGUAGE="Language Neutral [0x0]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="Spirit_Caliburn_Micro_v1.0.vshost.exe" SIZE="11600" CHECKSUM="0x457DC41D" BIN_FILE_VERSION="10.0.30319.1" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="10.0.30319.1" PRODUCT_VERSION="10.0.30319.1" FILE_DESCRIPTION="vshost32.exe" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Microsoft (R) Visual Studio (R) 2010" FILE_VERSION="10.0.30319.1" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="vshost32.exe" INTERNAL_NAME="vshost32.exe" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x1" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x4CDB" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="10.0.30319.1" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="10.0.30319.1" LINK_DATE="03/18/2010 11:02:35" UPTO_LINK_DATE="03/18/2010 11:02:35" VER_LANGUAGE="Language Neutral [0x0]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="System.ComponentModel.Composition.Codeplex.dll" SIZE="231424" CHECKSUM="0x143F36D5" BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="System.ComponentModel.Composition" FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="System.ComponentModel.Composition.Codeplex.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="System.ComponentModel.Composition.Codeplex.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x3A36A" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" LINK_DATE="10/07/2010 23:35:20" UPTO_LINK_DATE="10/07/2010 23:35:20" VER_LANGUAGE="Language Neutral [0x0]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="System.Windows.Interactivity.dll" SIZE="39936" CHECKSUM="0x1B5DDD86" BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="System.Windows.Interactivity" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="System.Windows.Interactivity" FILE_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="System.Windows.Interactivity.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="System.Windows.Interactivity.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x10C86" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" LINK_DATE="05/26/2010 01:12:04" UPTO_LINK_DATE="05/26/2010 01:12:04" VER_LANGUAGE="Language Neutral [0x0]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="WPFToolkit.Extended.dll" SIZE="111104" CHECKSUM="0xDE493382" BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.2.0.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.2.0.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="1.2.0.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Extended WPF Toolkit" PRODUCT_NAME="Extended WPF Toolkit" FILE_VERSION="1.2.0.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="WPFToolkit.Extended.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="WPFToolkit.Extended.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright ©  2010" VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.2.0.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.2.0.0" LINK_DATE="11/07/2010 22:18:37" UPTO_LINK_DATE="11/07/2010 22:18:37" VER_LANGUAGE="Language Neutral [0x0]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="de\System.Windows.Interactivity.resources.dll" SIZE="6656" CHECKSUM="0xAA6D57B7" BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="System.Windows.Interactivity" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="System.Windows.Interactivity" FILE_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="System.Windows.Interactivity.resources.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="System.Windows.Interactivity.resources.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten." VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x49B1" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" LINK_DATE="05/26/2010 01:13:06" UPTO_LINK_DATE="05/26/2010 01:13:06" VER_LANGUAGE="German (Germany) [0x407]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="en\System.Windows.Interactivity.resources.dll" SIZE="6656" CHECKSUM="0xA03B3A84" BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="System.Windows.Interactivity" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="System.Windows.Interactivity" FILE_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="System.Windows.Interactivity.resources.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="System.Windows.Interactivity.resources.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x10E3C" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" LINK_DATE="05/26/2010 01:12:05" UPTO_LINK_DATE="05/26/2010 01:12:05" VER_LANGUAGE="Language Neutral [0x0]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="es\System.Windows.Interactivity.resources.dll" SIZE="6656" CHECKSUM="0x2E7F3C00" BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="System.Windows.Interactivity" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="System.Windows.Interactivity" FILE_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="System.Windows.Interactivity.resources.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="System.Windows.Interactivity.resources.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. Reservados todos los derechos." VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0xD41F" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" LINK_DATE="05/26/2010 01:15:59" UPTO_LINK_DATE="05/26/2010 01:15:59" VER_LANGUAGE="Spanish (Spain, International Sort) [0xc0a]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="fr\System.Windows.Interactivity.resources.dll" SIZE="6656" CHECKSUM="0x2883F624" BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="System.Windows.Interactivity" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="System.Windows.Interactivity" FILE_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="System.Windows.Interactivity.resources.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="System.Windows.Interactivity.resources.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits réservés." VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0xF095" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" LINK_DATE="05/26/2010 01:14:04" UPTO_LINK_DATE="05/26/2010 01:14:04" VER_LANGUAGE="French (France) [0x40c]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="it\System.Windows.Interactivity.resources.dll" SIZE="6656" CHECKSUM="0x38D4200D" BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="System.Windows.Interactivity" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="System.Windows.Interactivity" FILE_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="System.Windows.Interactivity.resources.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="System.Windows.Interactivity.resources.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. Tutti i diritti riservati." VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0xCD08" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" LINK_DATE="05/26/2010 01:15:01" UPTO_LINK_DATE="05/26/2010 01:15:01" VER_LANGUAGE="Italian (Italy) [0x410]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="ja\System.Windows.Interactivity.resources.dll" SIZE="7168" CHECKSUM="0xC722FF2E" BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="System.Windows.Interactivity" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="System.Windows.Interactivity" FILE_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="System.Windows.Interactivity.resources.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="System.Windows.Interactivity.resources.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0xC1B3" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" LINK_DATE="05/26/2010 01:17:56" UPTO_LINK_DATE="05/26/2010 01:17:56" VER_LANGUAGE="Japanese (Japan) [0x411]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="ko\System.Windows.Interactivity.resources.dll" SIZE="6656" CHECKSUM="0xD97BF9A" BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="System.Windows.Interactivity" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="System.Windows.Interactivity" FILE_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="System.Windows.Interactivity.resources.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="System.Windows.Interactivity.resources.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0xE2B4" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" LINK_DATE="05/26/2010 01:16:57" UPTO_LINK_DATE="05/26/2010 01:16:57" VER_LANGUAGE="Korean (Korea) [0x412]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="zh-Hans\System.Windows.Interactivity.resources.dll" SIZE="6656" CHECKSUM="0xBD733777" BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="System.Windows.Interactivity" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="System.Windows.Interactivity" FILE_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="System.Windows.Interactivity.resources.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="System.Windows.Interactivity.resources.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="版权所有 (c) Microsoft Corporation。保留所有权利。" VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x2FF8" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" LINK_DATE="05/26/2010 01:19:51" UPTO_LINK_DATE="05/26/2010 01:19:51" VER_LANGUAGE="Chinese (Simplified, PRC) [0x804]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="zh-Hant\System.Windows.Interactivity.resources.dll" SIZE="6656" CHECKSUM="0xE9B86AF8" BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="System.Windows.Interactivity" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="System.Windows.Interactivity" FILE_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="System.Windows.Interactivity.resources.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="System.Windows.Interactivity.resources.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0xAB63" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.20525.0" LINK_DATE="05/26/2010 01:18:54" UPTO_LINK_DATE="05/26/2010 01:18:54" VER_LANGUAGE="Chinese (Traditional, Taiwan) [0x404]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" />
</EXE>
<EXE NAME="KERNELBASE.dll" FILTER="CMI_FILTER_THISFILEONLY">
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="KernelBase.dll" SIZE="269824" CHECKSUM="0xAC828268" BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.1.7600.16385" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.1.7600.16385" PRODUCT_VERSION="6.1.7600.16385" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Windows NT BASE API Client DLL" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Microsoft® Windows® Operating System" FILE_VERSION="6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="Kernelbase" INTERNAL_NAME="Kernelbase" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x4D82C" LINKER_VERSION="0x60001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.1.7600.16385" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.1.7600.16385" LINK_DATE="07/14/2009 01:14:07" UPTO_LINK_DATE="07/14/2009 01:14:07" EXPORT_NAME="KERNELBASE.dll" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" FILE_ID="0000e8839fe875223738c79f842618b7075d36a4b1a1" PROGRAM_ID="0000f519feec486de87ed73cb92d3cac802400000000" />
</EXE>
<EXE NAME="kernel32.dll" FILTER="CMI_FILTER_THISFILEONLY">
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="kernel32.dll" SIZE="836608" CHECKSUM="0xC7CF9264" BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.1.7600.16385" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.1.7600.16385" PRODUCT_VERSION="6.1.7600.16385" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Windows NT BASE API Client DLL" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Microsoft® Windows® Operating System" FILE_VERSION="6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="kernel32" INTERNAL_NAME="kernel32" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0xD900E" LINKER_VERSION="0x60001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.1.7600.16385" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.1.7600.16385" LINK_DATE="07/14/2009 01:14:06" UPTO_LINK_DATE="07/14/2009 01:14:06" EXPORT_NAME="KERNEL32.dll" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" FILE_ID="00008adee2374743f876efca279bd2bdb8e56594f46d" PROGRAM_ID="0000f519feec486de87ed73cb92d3cac802400000000" />
</EXE>
</DATABASE>
```

**I check the event viewer:**

**Error 1:**

*Application: Spirit_Caliburn_Micro_v1.0.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
Stack:
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(System.Exception, System.Xaml.IXamlLineInfo, System.Uri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(System.Xaml.XamlReader, System.Xaml.IXamlObjectWriterFactory, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterSettings, System.Uri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(System.Xaml.XamlReader, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.Permissions.XamlAccessLevel, System.Uri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(System.IO.Stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(System.Object, System.Uri)
   at Spirit.App.InitializeComponent()
   at Spirit.App.Main()*

**Error 2:**

F*aulting application name: Spirit_Caliburn_Micro_v1.0.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x4d1e2b87
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7600.16385, time stamp: 0x4a5bdbdf
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0000b727
Faulting process id: 0xb54
Faulting application start time: 0x01cba91f098ee071
Faulting application path: C:\Users\Jan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\C#\Pokec_Messenger\ver.beta\Pokec__Messenger\Spirit_Caliburn_Micro_v1.0\bin\Release\Spirit_Caliburn_Micro_v1.0.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 47a0a6e6-1512-11e0-b7ae-005056c00008*

**TO Hans Passant**

I don’tknow where I must pust event handler for AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandedException. I try this:

```
  [Export(typeof(IShellViewModel))]
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<object>, IShellViewModel
{

    AppDomain _currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;

    public void MyHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
    {
        var e = (Exception)args.ExceptionObject;
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }


    public  ShellViewModel()
    {
        _currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyHandler);
    }


}
```

But I doesn’t show any exception, I get same error as first.

Answer (score 4):

Write an event handler for AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandedException and log or display the value of e.ExceptionObject.ToString().  That's good enough to give you enough info about the unhandled exception 95% of the time without having to drag a debugger to the machine.

Answer (score 2):

Just going to expand on Hans' answer here with a little twist. You have a WPF application, I recommend the following...

In the App.xaml, set up this tag under Application:

```
<Application DispatcherUnhandledException="Application_DispatcherUnhandledException">
```

Then just write the error to file (writing to the Event Viewer might not work if you don't have proper permissions to create an event source, so its just easier to log to file):

```
private void Application_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    string error = "Exception during runtime: " + e.Exception.ToString();
    StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("Errors.txt");
    file.Write(error);
    file.Flush();
    file.Close();
    file.Dispose();
}
```